# Probability generating function of the sum of two random variables

Tags: probability-theory, generating-functions

Let two $\mathbf{N}$-valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ be given, and let $\phi_X(s) = \sum_k \mathbf{P}(X = k) s^k$ and $\phi_Y(s) = \sum_k \mathbf{P}(Y = k) s^k$ be their respective probability generating functions.

It is stated in *Probability and Statistics by Example*, Suhov and Kelbert, p. 59, that the following two conditions are equivalent.

(i) $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

(ii) $\phi_{X + Y}(s) = \phi_X(s) \phi_Y(s)$.

I don't have a problem with the fact that (i) implies (ii). However, I don't understand why the converse is true.

The only justification offered in the book is that it follows from the uniqueness of the coefficients of a power series. But I don't understand why the fact that $X + Y$ has the same distribution as if $X$ and $Y$ were independent ought to imply that they are in fact independent.

Can anybody fill in the details of the argument, or else refer me to an easily accessible source? Thanks.

Comment: A point of clarification: statement (ii) does **not** mean that "$X+Y$ has the same distribution as if $X$ and $Y$ were independent."  What (ii) says is that the PGF of the sum of $X+Y$ is equal to the product of the PGFs of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Isn't (ii) equivalent to that, at least if we accept the truth of the implication (i) $\rightarrow$ (ii)? After all, two random variables have the same distribution if and only if they have the same generating function, don't they?

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}
\text{Given that}:
\\
\phi_{X+Y}(s) & = \sum_{k\in\mathcal D(X+Y)} \mathsf P(X+Y=k)\; s^k
\\ & = \sum_{x\in\mathcal D(X)} \;\sum_{y\in \mathcal D(Y)} \mathsf P(X=x, Y=y)\; s^{x+y}
\\[2ex] 
\text{And that}
\\
\phi_X(s)\phi_Y(s) & = (\sum_{x\in\mathcal D(X)} \mathsf P(X=x)\; s^x )\cdot( \sum_{y\in\mathcal D(Y)} \mathsf P(Y=y)\; s^y)
\\
& = \sum_{x\in\mathcal D(X)}\sum_{y\in\mathcal D(Y)} \mathsf P(X=x)\mathsf P(Y=y)\; s^{x+y}
\\[2ex]
\text{And that independence means:}
\\ X\bot Y & \iff \mathsf P(X=x , Y=y) = \mathsf P(X=x)\mathsf P(Y=y) 
\\[2ex]
\text{Therefore } & \text{ for all X, Y using that probability generating function:}
\\ & \text{ Independence is a necessary and sufficient condition to declare that}
\\ & \text{ the the pgf of the sum, $X+Y$, is equal to the product of the pgfs of $X$ and $Y$.}
\\ X\bot Y & \iff \phi_{X+Y}(s) = \phi_X(s)\phi_Y(s)
\end{align}$

---

**Edit Summary**

Updated to be clear about the domains of the sum, and why we can switch from summing all k in the domain of X+Y to double summing over all x in the domain of X and all y in the domain of Y.  It's basically about expectations.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{z\in \mathcal D(X+Y)} s^z\;\mathsf P(X+Y=z)
& = \sum_{z\in \mathcal D(X+Y)} s^z\; \sum_{x\in\mathcal D(X)} \mathsf P(X=x\cap X+Y=z) & \text{Law of Total Probability}
\\ 
& = \sum_{z\in \mathcal D(X+Y)} s^z \sum_{x\in\mathcal D(X)} \mathsf P(X=x\cap Y=z-x)
& \text{Equivalence of events}
\\ 
& = \sum_{x\in\mathcal D(X)} \sum_{z\in \mathcal D(X+Y\mid X=x)} s^{z} \mathsf P(X=x\cap Y=z-x)
& \text{by reordering the summations}
\\ 
& = \sum_{x\in\mathcal D(X)} \sum_{y\in \mathcal D(Y)} s^{x+y} \mathsf P(X=x \cap Y=y)
& \text{by change of index}
\\[3ex]
\text{Alternatively:}
\\
\mathsf E_{X+Y}[s^{X+Y}] & = \mathsf E_X[\mathsf E_{X+Y\mid X}[s^{X+Y}\mid X]]
& \text{Conditional Expectation}
\\ & = \mathsf E_X[s^X \mathsf E_{Y\mid X}[s^{Y}\mid X]]
& \text{Linearity of Expectation}
\\[3ex]
\therefore 
\mathsf E_{X+Y}[s^{X+Y}]
& = \mathsf E_X[s^X \mathsf E_Y[s^Y]] & \text{by independence}
\\ & = \mathsf E_X[s^X]\times \mathsf E_Y[s^Y] & \text{by linearity of expectation}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Since the functions $\phi_{X + Y}(s)$ and $\phi_X(s) \phi_Y(s)$ are equal, that tells me that their $s^l$-coefficients must be equal for each $l$, that is, $\sum_{x + y = l} \mathbf{P}(X = x, Y = y) = \sum_{x + y = l} \mathbf{P}(X = x) \mathbf{P}(Y=y)$. I don't understand why it follows from this that $\mathbf{P}(X = x, Y = y) = \mathbf{P}(X = x) \mathbf{P}(Y=y)$ for all $x$, $y$.

Comment: @Dave It is because the domain of the sum is all possible values of $X+Y$, and sum over the domain of $X+Y$ is the double sum over the domains of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but which part of this is dealing with the "necessary" implication (ii) $\implies$ (i)?

Comment: @Graham Kemp. I don't disagree with your expressions for $\phi_{X + Y}(s)$ and $\phi_X(s)\phi_Y(s)$. My concern is the interpretation of what it means to say that the functions are equal. The first power series is $\sum_l [\sum_{x + y = l} P(X=x,Y=y)]s^l$. The second is $\sum_l [\sum_{x + y = l} P(X=x) P(Y=y)] s^l$. In order for the two functions to be equal, it is necessary and sufficient that for every $l$, the inner sums defining the $s^l$ coefficients be equal. It doesn't follow in an obvious way that each term *within* one of those sums is equal to the corresponding term in the other.

Comment: @Dave.  Iff $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables then *by definition*: $\forall x \in \mathbb X, \forall y \in \mathbb Y: \mathsf P(X=x, Y=y) = \mathsf P(X=x)\mathsf P(Y=y)$

Comment: @Graham Kemp. I agree with that. Graham, the more I read your answer, the more it appears to me that you're concerned with the direction "(i) implies (ii)" rather than "(ii) implies (i)." You can't assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, because that's what you're asked to prove.

Answer (score 1):

> A dimensional analysis shows that the implication (ii) $\implies$ (i) does not hold.

Let $p_n=P(X=n)$, $q_n=P(Y=n)$ and $r_{n,k}=P(X=n,Y=k)$ for every $n$ and $k$, then, as the OP knows, (ii) means that for every nonnegative $n$, $$P(X+Y=n)=\sum_{k=0}^nP(X=k)P(Y=n-k).$$
On the other hand, $$[X+Y=n]=\bigcup_{k=0}^n[X=k,Y=k-n],$$ and each union in the RHS is disjoint hence (ii) is equivalent to the condition that, for every $n$, $$\sum_{k=0}^nr_{k,n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^np_kq_{n-k}.$$
Furthermore, for every $(n,k)$, $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty r_{n,i}=p_n,\qquad\sum_{i=0}^\infty r_{i,k}=q_k.$$
Assume that $0\leqslant X\leqslant N$ and $0\leqslant Y\leqslant M$ almost surely and that $(p_n)$ and $(q_n)$ are fixed, then the distribution of $(X,Y)$ depends on $NM$ free parameters $r_{n,k}$. On the other hand, $0\leqslant X+Y\leqslant N+M$ almost surely hence condition (ii) is an affine system of $N+M+1$ equations.

If $NM\gt N+M+1$, say, for $N=M=3$, the latter cannot fully determine the former hence the claim that the identity $\varphi_{X+Y}=\varphi_X\cdot\varphi_Y$ implies the independence of $X$ and $Y$ does not hold.

Here is a distribution on the set $\{0,1,2,3\}\times\{0,1,2,3\}$ such that, if $(X,Y)$ has this distribution then $X$ and $Y$ are both binomial $(3,\frac12)$ and $X+Y$ is binomial $(6,\frac12)$, and yet, $(X,Y)$ is not independent (for simplicity, the node $(n,k)$ carries the weight $64\cdot r_{n,k}$, for example $r_{1,2}=\frac9{64}$):
$$\begin{matrix}(3)&7&0&0&1\\(2)&0&4&14&6\\(1)&\color{red}{0}&14&9&1\\(0)&1&6&1&0\\n/k&(0)&(1)&(2)&(3)\end{matrix}$$
The sums of the rows and of the columns are proportional to $(1,3,3,1)$, the third line of Pascal triangle, the sums of the diagonals in the direction NW-SE are $(1,6,15,20,15,6,1)$, the sixth line of Pascal triangle, hence $X$, $Y$ and $X+Y$ have the desired distributions and yet $(X,Y)$ is not independent since, for example, $P(X=1,Y=0)=\color{red}{0}\ne\frac38\cdot\frac18$.

Another example, based on the uniform distributions on  the set $\{0,1,2,3\}$ (this time, the node $(n,k)$ carries the weight $16\cdot r_{n,k}$): $$\begin{matrix}(3)&3&0&0&1\\(2)&0&0&2&2\\(1)&0&2&1&1\\(0)&1&2&1&0\\n/k&(0)&(1)&(2)&(3)\end{matrix}$$
And finally a minimal example, based on the uniform distributions on  the set $\{0,1,2\}$ (this time, the node $(n,k)$ carries the weight $9\cdot r_{n,k}$): $$\begin{matrix}(2)&2&0&1\\(1)&0&1&2\\(0)&1&2&0\\n/k&(0)&(1)&(2)\end{matrix}$$

Comment: I generally agree with your argument. However, I count $(N+1)(M+1)$ variables $r_{nk}$ in all, and $2M + 2N + 3$ equations. When $M=N=3$, there are more variables than equations. The system has at least one solution, which corresponds to the case of independence, and therefore has at least a line of solutions. The only additional constraint is $r_{nk} \geq 0$, but this will be satisfied for solutions near the independence solution, so long as each $r_{nk} > 0$ for the independence solution, that is, so long as $p_n, q_n > 0$. The counterexample is nice.

Comment: The difference is that I consider $(p_n)$ and $(q_n)$ as fixed, hence my count of independent equations is lower--but the end result is the same.

Comment: Why aren't you counting equations like $r_{00} + r_{01} + r_{02} + r_{03} = p_0$? I see four of those, four with $q$'s, and seven of the other kind. And I see 16 $r$'s, not 9. Where do we differ? I'm counting the $p$'s and $q$'s as fixed as well.

Comment: If all the $p_i$ and $q_j$ are fixed then $r_{i,j}$ for $0\leqslant i,j\leqslant2$ determine the complete array, thus 9 *independent* unknowns. As I said, there are several ways to carry the dimensional argument and they all lead to the same conclusion.

Comment: Okay, I see. I think your point of view is better than mine because of the eight equations with $p$'s and $q$'s, only seven appear to be independent. The result is that you have one additional free dimension in your solution set, so you have at least a plane of solutions, rather than a line. I would accept your answer, but I no longer have the cookies from my browser when I asked the question, and I didn't have an account. Thanks!