Does the PGF of the sum of RVs being the product of the PGFs imply independence?
If $X$ and $Y$ are independent integer-valued random variables and their probability generating functions $G_X(s), G_Y(s)$ are such that $G_X(s)G_Y(s) = G_{X + Y}(s)$, are $X$ and $Y$ necessarily independent?

As written ("If $X$ and $Y$ are independent ... are $X$ and $Y$ necessarily independent?") -- yes

Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916383/probability-generating-function-of-the-sum-of-two-random-variables?noredirect=1

Just to be clear: look at Did's answer in the question I linked, not Kemp's.  The correct conclusion is that the equation does not imply independence.
